# x.appendChild is not a function (JSX)

Tags: adobe, extendscript

What am I possibly missing here?
This is to be run on Adobe InDesign.

The code I'm having problem with:

```
x = "<formField/>";
x.appendChild("<name>" + ff.name; + "</name>");
x.appendChild("<type>" + String(ff.constructor.name); + "</type>");
```

The debugger returns:

```
x.appendChild is not a function
```

Here is the screenshot::

[image: Screenshot from the bug]

Comment: Please include your code *in your question*, not as a screenshot

Comment: @Joel done sir. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stands in your variable declaration.

```js
x = "<formField/>";
```

At this point x is a String instance. String don't have appendChild method.
You need to convert your String into XML Object instance. This has appendChild method.

```js
x = XML ( "<formField/>" );
```

But as ExtendScript offers E4X, or in other words, XML as Javascript Objects, you can simply use :

```js
x = <formField/>;
```

And now you are free to go :

```js
x.appendChild ( <name>{ff.name}</name> );
```

Voilà…

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you a zillion times.